# Pretty print folder structure using linux terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

How can you pretty print a directory structure with all subdirectories to the deepest level in the linux terminal(ubuntu)?
This is an example of such a pretty print output for a `mysite` folder:

```
mysite
|-- manage.py
|-- mysite
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- urls.py
    |-- wsgi.py
|-- polls
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- static
        |-- css
            |-- styles.css
|-- templates
    |-- polls
        |-- index.html
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) command. You might need to install it if it is not already installed.

Answer (score 1):

A shell only version, usage: dirtree

```
DIR=${1:-`pwd`}
SPACING=${2:-|} 
cd $DIR 
for x in * ; do
  [ -d $DIR/$x ] && echo "$SPACING\`-{"$x && $0 $DIR/$x "$SPACING "
done
```

Comment: Hard to follow this, and hard to use. It doesn’t want to run for me. (I’m not on ubuntu though, but this *looks* portable enough.) What do you mean, `usage: dirtree`?